# Convert SIint16 to float on iPhone4

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-audio, vdsp

I am developing an app which uses simple pitch perception and it runs fine in the Xcode Simulator. The app loads in the iPhone 4 and I can navigate the app but no output is shown . I have started to debug and find that when I convert Sint16 to float I get an overflow error.
I have tried vDSP and a simple loop.

simplified code n=1536

```
sampleBuffer = (SInt16*) malloc(n);
floatSamples = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*n);
    // Convert SInt 16 to float
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    floatSamples[i] = (float)samples[i];

}

//vDSP_vflt16(samples,1,floatSamples,1,n);
```

This results in

```
-0.000000
 -0.000000
 -0.000000
 964957789008661674961361960960.000000
 -5629971079108504200413184.000000
 -inf
 35116851871418647838720.000000
 -inf
 0.000000
 0.000000
 0.000000
 -1233.760620
 288987875649316726325339192557568.000000
 -0.000000
 -0.000000
 -0.000000
 -7508525217561044282816045485425426432.000000
 -656399043038732589927376093184.000000
 0.000000
 -0.000053
 9470091451011432448.000000
 -24555002
```

similar result from vDSP
Everything is fine in the simulator on iPhone 4s all the vDSP calculations work.
iPhone is running ios7.1.2 and xCode 6 on MacBook pro.
Just looking for a clue really.

Answer (score 1):

The code
`sampleBuffer = (SInt16*) malloc(n);`
allocates n bytes, not n `SInt16` values.

You need:
`sampleBuffer = (SInt16*) malloc(sizeof(SInt16)*n);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is one of my retirement hobbies so I can get a bit dozy. You are right it was a memory allocation problem. I was using  someone else's code as a base and hadn't followed the process through properly when I allocated memory for the vectors for the vDSP I was implementing .Does the simulator allocate  memory in larger blocks so it wouldn't get overwritten? That would perhaps explain why the simulator didn't give spurious results.

Comment: Memory allocation is in large blocks at the system level and subdivided/allocated, assigned, recovered and combined as possible. So it is possible that there was unallocated space at the end. If you want memory protections there are options in the Schemes but they have performance side effects.